# Joomla 2.5 - component fatal error

Tags: joomla2.5

When I make component in Joomla 2.5 I had this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function reset() on a non-object in
/var/www/html/joomla/libraries/joomla/application/component/modeladmin.php
on line 850
```

Comment: Please don't double post.

Answer (score -1):

I found‌ :when  click  on publish or unpublish first run this controller quite in my project this name is :

notic:run first this file

com_contactus/controllers/categories.php

```
<?php
defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die();
jimport ('joomla.application.component.controlleradmin');

      echo "run first this file ";

 class contactusControllerCategories extends JControllerAdmin
{

    public function getModel($name='Category',$prefix='contactusModel',$config=array('ignore_request'=>true))
    {

        $model = parent::getModel($name,$prefix,$config);
        return $model;
    }
}
```

after run that Top file rund this file Of course gettable method

com_contactus/models/category.php

```
<?php
defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die();
jimport ('joomla.application.component.modeladmin');

class contactusModelCategory extends JModelAdmin
{

    public function getTable($type='Category',$prefix='contactusTable',$config=array())
    {
       echo "second "; 
        return JTable::getInstance ($type,$prefix,$config);

    }


    protected function loadFormData()
    {

        $data = JFactory::getApplication()->getUserState('com_contactus.edit.category.data',array());
        if (empty($data))
        {
            $data = $this->getItem();
        }
        return $data;
    }



    function getForm($data=array(),$loadData=true)
    {

        $form = $this->loadForm('com_contactus.category','Category',array('control'=>'jform' , 'load_data'=>$loadData));
        return $form;

    }

}
```

after that run towice files rund this file for run

com_contactus/tables/category.php

```
<?php
defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die();
jimport ('joomla.database.table');
   echo "three ";
   die();
class contactusTableCategory extends JTable
{

    public function __construct (&$db)
    {

        parent::__construct('#__contactus','id',$db);
    }

}



 one of  my wrong:
    . I put the wrong  tabels instead tables name in project
```